# PHP export .CSV file with chinese character

Tags: php, fputcsv

I'm trying to export my .csv file with chinese character using PHP. Instead the data that I've after export is ??? for my chinese character, English character are just working fine. Please have a look on my code below and let me know where's the problem seems to be, Thank you.

PHP

```
$a = mysqli_query($db, "select * from remark_type where remark_code = ".$_POST["code"]."");
                $getrow = mysqli_fetch_array($a);
                header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
                header('Content-type: application/csv;charset:UTF-8');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$getrow["title"]."_".$_POST["year"].'.csv');
                echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";

// data of my csv file code here

$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
                foreach ($newname as $line) {
                    if($_POST["method"] == 2)
                        fputcsv($file, $line);
                    else
                    {
                         fputcsv($file, $line);
                    }
                }

                fclose($file);
```

Comment: How are you verifying that you are only seeing question marks? In a browser, in Excel, something else? The `header` stuff is about the transport itself and shouldn't affect the file in any way. If you are using a browser-based renderer, however, it might be interpreting that. You should confirm both that your source data (the database) actually has the code points that you expect, and that they are being transported to PHP correctly, and you should also inspect the file received at a binary level to confirm if the problem is with the generation or the renderer.

Comment: FYI, The bowser can show the chinese character correctly and also I have a function where user may download a pdf file of the data show in the web browser and the pdf file show the chinese character correctly too, for now it's only the csv file showing ??? for chinese character

Answer (score 1):

add this after fopen

```
 fprintf(<openFileVariable>, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF));
```

Example

```
$file = fopen($file_path, 'w');
fprintf($file, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF));
fputcsv($file, ["From", $request->get("start_date")]);
fputcsv($file, ["To", $request->get("end_date")]);
```